# Use the definition of limit to prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^2}{x+1}=\infty$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Use the definition of limit to prove that $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^2}{x+1}=\infty$$

Attempt

to show
$0 < |x - a| < \delta \quad \Rightarrow \quad |f(x) - l| < \epsilon$, But here,  $a=\infty=l$.

If $a=\infty$, we show that for given $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $K≥0$ such that, if $|x|>K$, $|f(x)-l|<ϵ$

But here, $l=\infty$, what to do?

Comment: The $\epsilon-\delta$ definition is only for finite limits. The definition of $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = +\infty$ is that for any $M$, there exists an $x_0$ such that $f(x) \geq M$ whenever $x \geq x_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need the following definition

**Definition** We say that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, if given $M>0$, we can find $K>0$ such that for all $x>K$, we have $f(x)>M$.

We have to prove that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{x+1}=\infty.$$

**Proof:** Let $M>0$. By using the Archimedean Property, we can find $K\in\Bbb N$ such that $K>2M$. Thus, if $x>K\geq 1$ then 
$$\frac{x^2}{x+\color\red 1}>\frac{x^2}{x+\color\red x}=\frac{x^2}{2x}=\frac{x}{2}>\frac{K}{2}>M.$$
Use the definition and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M>0$. Suppose $x>1$. You have that $\frac{x}{x+1}>\frac{1}{2}$ for all $x>1$ and thus $$\frac{x^2}{x+1}>\frac{x}{2},$$
if $x>1$. Take $N=2M$, and thus $$\frac{x^2}{x+1}>M,$$
if $x>N$ what prove the claim.